# Is there a list of npm libraries that are written in ES-6 or being written in ES-6?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I am starting a new NodeJS project. I see I can use most of the ES6 features in V8 bundled with latest nodeJS by using --harmony. And it works well. Actually gives good opportunity to learn ES6.
However NodeJS is based on many libraries and frameworks (like I use restify and lodash node). 
But they are predominately in ES5. 
I don't think things will break if I use existing libs. But my questions are:

1. Is there a list of ES6 libs available for node (like npm-es6)
2. When these frameworks and libs catch up with ES6 - how much rework would be required
3. Finally - is there any performance difference between ES6 vs ES5 that anyone is aware of?

Comment: What do you mean by "ES6 libs"? A library is a library, and normally it doesn't matter what dialect of JS it's written in.

Comment: Well JavaScript is not compiled - which means execution depends on runtime interpreter. So if interpreter is not backward compatible - we run in risk of breaking. I hope v8 is backward compat - as it has started supporting es6.

Comment: @rahul Javascript can indeed be compiled. [It is in v8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine)) anyway, using a JIT compiler. Nit-picking I know, but just to highlight that for future readers

Comment: hmm - good thing to know and probably something to explore in future. Thanks RGraham

Answer (score 1):

It is always going to be "safe" to use ES6 because you can transpile ES6 to older javascript via babel. (and even output human-readable transpiled-javascript). ES6 doesn't have any breaking or conflicting syntax, so ES5 code runs without a hitch on ES6 engines.

1. Not that I'm aware of.
2. None, hopefully!
3. That is a very broad question! I'd have to generally say the latest version v8 is faster than the v8 of es5 days.